# iOS App doesnt prompt to enable notifications

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I have generated the .p12 certs for push

Ive enabled push in the app entitlements via xcode but when starting the app I never get the prompt asking if I would like to enable push notifications.

Ive ran in a simulator and on a real device but still nothing, on that note do you get this prompt while in a simulator ? curious as it would speed up my testing

Update: I have also checked my entitlements file and there is no mention of push notifications

Comment: You need to write code requesting permission to show notifications.  Have you done that?

Comment: No I have not. I thought that the prompt was something which the OS does itself once you enable notifications. can you show an example for ionic/JS